# Java Calculator (need assistance for my first project)

Tags: java

This is my first try on Java. The project is a calculator that takes a number, an operator signal (+,-,*,/), and another number to create an equation and give the final value of it, asking after that if the user wants to restart the program for another equation or not. I would like to know if there is anything that I can do to improve my code.
Thanks!

```
/*
Name: Felipe de Araujo
Project #: 1
*/

import java.util.Scanner; //Importing API.

public class Calculator {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int a = 1; //Creating variable for the first while loop.
    System.out.println("Welcome to the calculator!"); //Program introduction.

    while (a == 1){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Creating the input.

        double firstNumber, secondNumber, result; char operator; //Creating all variables.

        //Program asking for the first number.
        System.out.print("First Number: ");
        firstNumber = input.nextDouble();

        //Program asking for the operator
        System.out.print(firstNumber + " (+,-,*,/): ");
        operator = input.next(".").charAt(0);

        int repeat = 1; //Creating variable for the next while loop.

        //Evaluating the operator to determine if it is inside the criteria (+,-,*,/).
        if (operator == '+' || operator == '-' || operator == '*' || operator == '/'){
            System.out.print(firstNumber + " " + operator + " Second Number: "); //If the operator is inside the criteria than start
                                                                                 //asking for the second number.
        }
        else { //If the operator is not inside the criteria run the loop until the user type something that is.
            while (repeat == 1){
                System.out.print(operator + " not recognized, please select between (+,-,*,/): ");
                operator = input.next(".").charAt(0);
                if (operator == '+' || operator == '-' || operator == '*' || operator == '/') {
                    System.out.print(firstNumber + " " + operator + " Second Number: ");

                    repeat++;
                }
            }
        }

        secondNumber = input.nextDouble(); //Initialize the secondNumber variable to the number typed.

        //Equalling the variable result to the return given by the method calculatorMethod, with the variables given.
        result = calculatorMethod(firstNumber, secondNumber, operator);
        System.out.println(firstNumber + " " + operator + " " + secondNumber + " = " + result);//Printing the equation.
        System.out.println(" ");

        // Asking the user to continue the program for another operation.
        char out;//Creating the variable out.
        System.out.print("[y/Y] - continue | [n/N] or any other to end program: ");
        out = input.next(".").charAt(0);//Initializing the variable out to what was typed.

        //Verifying if the user wants to continue the program.
        if (out == 'y' || out == 'Y'){
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
        else {//If the users type anything besides y/Y the program will exit the main loop, ending the program.
            System.out.println("Bye!");
            a++;
        }
    }
}

//Declaring the calculatorMethod and all its behaviors.
private static double calculatorMethod(double a, double b, char c){

    if (c == '+'){
        return a + b;
    }
    else if (c == '-'){
        return  a - b;
    }
    else if (c == '*'){
        return a * b;
    }
    else {
        return a / b;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If your code is working fine and If you only need suggestions to improve your code, I would suggest you to post your code in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) forum.

Comment: The variable a == 1 is strange. I would replace it with a boolean. Do you already know about enums?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

hello and welcome to the Java world :) . Some tips :

1. Try to give clear name to your variables. 'a', 'b', 'c' could be complicated to understand.
2. Favor short methods to improve the readability of your code. For example you can create an other method which return an object of : separator + the two numbers and an other one which print the result.
3. You can use **switch(variable)** in your *calculatorMethod* method. For example :

   ```
   switch (c) { // you have to change the name of all the variables 'c', 'a' and 'b'
       case '+':
           return a + b;
       case '-':
           return a - b;
       case '*':
           return a * b;
       default:
           return a / b;
   }
   ```

   }
4. You can create an enum or a list with the different operators.
5. When you check the input operator, you can use a **while()** loop and delete the **if...else** loop. The condition of the while loop could be "while the operator is not the correct one (and so, not contained in the list of correct operators), loop again and again".
6. The scanner initialization **Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);** should be out the **while()** loop because you need to initialize only one time the scanner and in this case, you initialize X times (X refers to the numbers of loops).

Good luck :)